# NGINX - redirect all unconfigured subdomains

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain

I'm happy to join community and want to share with you with my little problem.

I've got wildcard entry for example.com in my DNS which points all subdomains to some machine

```
* IN A 172.172.172.172
```

While NGINX configuration for this domain contains only actively used subdomain names

```
server {
listen 10.0.0.1:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com
moskva.example.com www.moskva.example.com
tokyo.example.com www.tokyo.example.com;
...
}
```

What I want to achieve is directing all unconfigured subdomains like 'mistake.example.com' to specific address.
Is there any elegant way of solving this problem?

Best Regards
Arek

Answer (score 9):

This will instruct the site to redirect any unmatched traffic to example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 http://example.com;
}
```

Comment: You should user `default_server` instead of `default`. From Nginx documentation: “The default_server parameter appeared in version 0.8.21 thus deprecating the parameter default”.

Comment: yea I know, It's just a bad old habit :D, corrected my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can [set a default server section](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) like this:

```
server {
    listen       10.0.0.1:80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    ...
}
```